# ChecksSdkIntAtLeast is not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-annotations

I am trying to use [@ChecksSdkIntAtLeast](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/ChecksSdkIntAtLeast) annotation to convert our java utility functions into kotlin properties that would not require `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`.

But anyway I write the property, it stops red underlining code for both branches of `if`.

Demo:

```
@get:ChecksSdkIntAtLeast(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
val isAtLeastOreo: Boolean
    get() = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    manager.getNotificationChannel("general")
} else {
    manager.getNotificationChannel("general")        // CORRECTLY UNDERLINED
}

if (isAtLeastOreo) {
    manager.getNotificationChannel("general")
} else {
    manager.getNotificationChannel("general")        // NOT UNDERLINED - WHY??
}
```

Same thing happens if I make it into function instead of getter. The only working one would be using lambda, but then I am losing if-else construct and would require massive amount of places to refactor.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue.

Comment: @SamLu Please, star the problem on google issue tracker, thank you
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197428342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been reported on Aug 23. Waiting for response

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197428342